# How to make rows to column names in an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, associative-array

I want to convert rows to column names in associative array in PHP. My data is stored in a single variable `$salesone` in an associative array format.

Below is the data stored in variable `$salesone`.

```
[{"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Make":"Datsun", "Sales":0},
 {"Datetime":"2011-02-28", "Make":"Datsun", "Sales":0},
 {"Datetime":"2011-03-31", "Make":"Datsun", "Sales":0},
 {"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Make":"Fiat", "Sales":2150},
 {"Datetime":"2011-02-28", "Make":"Fiat", "Sales":1839},
 {"Datetime":"2011-03-31", "Make":"Fiat", "Sales":1860},
 {"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Make":"Ford", "Sales":10026},
 {"Datetime":"2011-02-28", "Make":"Ford", "Sales":9293},
 {"Datetime":"2011-03-31", "Make":"Ford", "Sales":10485}]
```

But google line chart unable to interpret it to draw line chart. It is giving me the below error:

> 'all the data on given axis must be of same data type'

I want the data in below format:

```
[{"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Datsun":0, "Fiat":2150, "Ford":10026},
{"Datetime":"2011-02-28", "Datsun":0, "Fiat":1839, "Ford":9293},
{"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Datsun":0, "Fiat":1860, "Ford":10845}]
```

How to transform this data programmatically in PHP? (it is stored as an associative array in `$salesone` variable).

Comment: Just determine first the date and use that in PHP condition functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code for your output :

```
<?php
$number = '[{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},
{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},
{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},
{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":2150},
{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1839},
{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1860},
{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Ford","Sales":10026},
{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Ford","Sales":9293},
{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Ford","Sales":10485}]';

$number = json_decode($number);
$output = array();
foreach($number as $value){
    $output[$value->Datetime]['Datetime'] = $value->Datetime;
    $output[$value->Datetime][$value->Make] = $value->Sales;
}
$output = array_values($output);
$output = json_encode($output);
echo $output;
```

Please Use Below Code For your Next Comment :

```
<?php
$number = '[{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},
{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},
{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},
{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":2150},
{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1839},
{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1860},
{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Ford","Sales":10026},
{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Ford","Sales":9293},
{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Ford","Sales":10485}]';

$number = json_decode($number);
$output = array();
foreach($number as $value){
    $output[$value->Datetime]['Datetime'] = $value->Datetime;
    $output[$value->Datetime][$value->Make] = $value->Sales;
}
$output = array_values($output);

$newOutput = array();
$counter = 0;
$colCounter = 0;
$colArray  = array();
foreach($output as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue){
        if(!array_key_exists($innerKey,$colArray)){
            $colArray[$innerKey] = $innerKey;
            $newOutput['cols'][$colCounter]['label'] = $innerKey;
            $newOutput['cols'][$colCounter]['type'] = ($innerKey == "Datetime")?"date":"string";

            $colCounter++;
        }
        $newOutput['rows'][$counter]['c'][]['v'] = ($innerKey == "Datetime")?"date(".date('Y,n,j',$innerValue).")":$innerValue;
    }
    $counter++;
}
$newOutput = json_encode($newOutput);
echo $newOutput;
?>
```

I think that is help your

Comment: Your Output Like This : [{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Datsun":0,"Fiat":2150,"Ford":10026},{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Datsun":0,"Fiat":1839,"Ford":9293},{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Datsun":0,"Fiat":1860,"Ford":10485}]

Comment: thanks a lot. Your help is much appreciated. If I want to again convert this string again like this: `{"cols":[{"label":"Datetime","type":"date"},{"label":"Datsun","type":"string"}, {"label":"Fiat","type":"string"}], "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 0, 31)"},{"v":"0"},{"v":2150}]},{"c":  [{"v":"Date(2011, 1, 28)"},{"v":"0"},{"v":1839}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 2, 31)"},{"v":"0"},{"v":1860}]}]}.` Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you Rahul for your reply on my answer

Comment: Output of Above Code Like : {"cols":[{"label":"Datetime","type":"date"},{"label":"Datsun","type":"string"},{"label":"Fiat","type":"string"},{"label":"Ford","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"date(1970,1,1)"},{"v":0},{"v":2150},{"v":10026}]},{"c":[{"v":"date(1970,1,1)"},{"v":0},{"v":1839},{"v":9293}]},{"c":[{"v":"date(1970,1,1)"},{"v":0},{"v":1860},{"v":10485}]}]}    is that match your answer

Comment: Thanks a lot javedrathod. But it is giving me error "A non well formed numeric value is encountered." at this line of code `$newOutput['rows'][$counter]['c'][]['v'] = ($innerKey == "Datetime")?"date(".Date('Y,n,j',$innerValue).")":$innerValue;`

Comment: please give me a json that you are using.

Comment: This is my json format: `[{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":2150},{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1839},{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1860}]`

Comment: Please use this and run and let me know if any error : $number = '[{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Datsun","Sales":0},{"Datetime":"2011-01-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":2150},{"Datetime":"2011-02-28","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1839},{"Datetime":"2011-03-31","Make":"Fiat","Sales":1860}]';

Comment: Please first check this json in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/  and after that it use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103090/discussion-between-rahul16590-and-javedrathod).

Answer (score 1):

You can use try this one. Hope it works

```
    $string='[{"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Make":"Datsun", "Sales":0},
     {"Datetime":"2011-02-28", "Make":"Datsun", "Sales":0},
     {"Datetime":"2011-03-31", "Make":"Datsun", "Sales":0},
     {"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Make":"Fiat", "Sales":2150},
     {"Datetime":"2011-02-28", "Make":"Fiat", "Sales":1839},
     {"Datetime":"2011-03-31", "Make":"Fiat", "Sales":1860},
     {"Datetime":"2011-01-31", "Make":"Ford", "Sales":10026},
     {"Datetime":"2011-02-28", "Make":"Ford", "Sales":9293},
     {"Datetime":"2011-03-31", "Make":"Ford", "Sales":10485}]';

    $array=json_decode($string,true);
    $newArray=array();
    $keyArray=array();
    $indexArray=array();
    $index=0;
    foreach ($array as $position => $dataArray)
    {
        if(!in_array($array[$position]['Datetime'], $keyArray))
        {
            $keyArray[]=$array[$position]['Datetime'];
            $indexArray[$array[$position]['Datetime']]=$index;
            $index++;
        }
    }
    foreach($array as $position => $dataArray)
    {
        foreach($dataArray as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key=='Datetime' && empty($newArray[$indexArray[$value]]['Datetime']))
            {
                $newArray[$indexArray[$value]]['Datetime']=$value;
            }
            else
            {
                $indexArray[$array[$position]['Datetime']];
                $newArray[$indexArray[$array[$position]['Datetime']]][$dataArray['Make']]=$dataArray['Sales'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($newArray);

    $newArray1=array();
    $colIndex=0;
    foreach($newArray as $index => $dataArray)
    {
        foreach($dataArray as $key => $value)
        {
            if(count($newArray1['cols'])!=4)
            {
                $type=($key=='Datetime') ? 'date' : 'string';
                $newArray1['cols'][$colIndex]['label']=$key;
                $newArray1['cols'][$colIndex]['type']=$type;
                $colIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                $colIndex=0;
            }
            if(preg_match('/^([\d]{4})-([\d]{2})-([\d]{2})$/',$value,$matches))
            {
                $value='Date('.$matches[1].', '.$matches[2].', '.$matches[3].')';
            }
            $newArray1['rows'][$index]['c'][]['v']=$value;;
        }
    }
    print_r($newArray1);
```

This will give you exact answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sahil. Your approach is much appreciated. But google charts needs rows and columns should be defined for google charts.  Now I need one small modification in the output format. I want to modify it as below:   `{"cols":[{"label":"Datetime","type":"date"},{"label":"Datsun","type":"string"}, {"label":"Fiat","type":"string"}], "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 0, 31)"},{"v":0},{"v":2150}]},{"c": [{"v":"Date(2011, 1, 28)"},{"v":0},{"v":1839}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 2, 31)"},{"v":0},{"v":1860}]}]}'

Comment: @rahul16590 welcome.. :) do you result in this format..?

Comment: @sahil...I need rows & columns  defined for json data, as google charts is unable to interpret the graph without rows and columns.

Comment: @rahul16590 sorry i took a long time.. bcoz .. i answer questions when i got time in office.. but i must appreciate your question ... i have edited my answer....